# how to create function that returns a functor with the same signature as the function?

Tags: c++, recursion, c++11, functor, state-machine

Is it possible in c++ to create function that returns a functor with the same signature as the function?

basicly, how to legalise `decltype(foo) foo();`.

or with functors:`function<function<function<...(void)>(void)>(void)>`

I'd like to use this for a state-machine where every state is a function that returns a functor to the next state of the object. I've now implemented it using enums, but I feel like there must be a better way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum functionenum{END,FOO,BAR,BAZ};

functionenum foo(){
    cout<<"FOO! > ";
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    if(s=="end") return END;
    if(s=="bar") return BAR;
                 return FOO;
}

functionenum bar(){
    cout<<"BAR! > ";
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    if(s=="end") return END;
    if(s=="baz") return BAZ;
                 return BAR;
}

functionenum baz(){
    cout<<"BAZ! > ";
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    if(s=="end") return END;
    if(s=="bar") return BAR;
    if(s=="foo") return FOO;
                 return BAZ;
}

void state(){
    auto f=foo;
    while(true){
        switch (f()){
        case FOO: f=foo; break;
        case BAR: f=bar; break;
        case BAZ: f=baz; break;
        case END: return;
        };
    };
}

int main(){
    state();
}
```

also: is there a less clunky way to phrase the question?

Comment: Why are you writing state machine code in C++ instead of VHDL?

Comment: Because I'm talking about the mathematical abstraction and not about an actual machine.

Comment: Well it depends what you mean by "return". Functors behave like funtions in a way, so the compiler will still evaluate the value of the functor before returning anything so you will end up with recursion.

Comment: I mean just return the functor without evaluating it. (as a function-pointer)

Comment: So you're trying to return the function `f` from `state`?

Comment: `boost::variant` has a builder that can take a recursive token: something similar for `std::function`?

Comment: I assume functors, not function pointers, will do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could break the type-recursion by wrapping the function in a struct:

```
#include <string>

struct state
{
    typedef state (*state_func)( const std::string &);
    state( state_func f): function(f){} //not explicit, for notational convenience
    state operator()( const std::string&arg) const
    {
        return function( arg);
    }
private:
    state_func function;

};

state f( const std::string &);
state g( const std::string &)
{
    return &f;
}
state f( const std::string &)
{
    return &g;
}

int main()
{
    state s(&f);
    s = s( "hello");
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: after comments by Yakk ('make it more generic') and Luc Danton ("Classic [GOTW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm)") I'm adding a more generic C++11 version below, that is based on the GOTW version.

```
/// Type that wraps functions that return functions with the same signature.
template<typename... Arguments>
struct SelfReturningFunction
{
    typedef SelfReturningFunction (*FunctionPointer)( Arguments...);
    SelfReturningFunction( FunctionPointer f): function(f){} 
    operator FunctionPointer() const
    {
        return function;
    }
private:
    FunctionPointer function;
};

// example usage
#include <string>

using state = SelfReturningFunction<const std::string&>;

state f( const std::string &);
state g( const std::string &)
{
    return &f;
}
state f( const std::string &)
{
    return &g;
}
state dead_end( const std::string &)
{
    return &dead_end;
}

int main()
{
    state s{&f};
    s = s( "hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be much improved by that `operator()`.

Comment: The only other changes I might be tempted by is making the `std::string` a `template` arg.  Oh and perfect forwarding in your `operator()`.

Comment: Yep, the argument should maybe even be an argument pack, but I just wanted to show an example where the state function has an argument. I'm a bit worried that further generalization would distract from the main point (Also: I'm still a C++98 programmer by reflex).